# how to split string by two regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to split string by string `!` (space before and after) and one char `|`.

```
function split (str) {
    return str.split (/\s!\s/)
}

result = split ("hello world ! hello | world! hi ");
console.log (result); // result must be: ["hello world", "hello", "world! hi "]
```

I cant figure out how to do it. Now what I done is spliting only by `!`. Plus char `|` need to be screened, because it means `OR` in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or in regular expression is `|`

so, if space before and after `|`

```
function split (str) {
    return str.split(/\s!\s|\s\|\s/);
}
```

else:

```
function split (str) {
    return str.split(/\s!\s|\|/);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
function split (str) {
    return str.split (/\s[!|]\s/)
}
```

This will break a string by either a `!` or `|` which is surrounded by whitespace characters.

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yrhFm/).

But in general, if you want to use a `|` (or any special character) as a literal you can escape it using a backslash (`\`), like this:

```
/\s!\s|\s\|\s/
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use pipe operator to include both:
use this regex `/ ! | \| /`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can (and should) do that with a character class [as p.s.w.g shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18952027/157247).

But the answer to the *general* question

> how to split string by two regular expressions

...is to use an "alternation":

```
str.split(/first expression|second expression/);
```

For instance:

```
str.split(/foo|bar/);
```

...would split on `foo` or `bar`.

In this case, it would be:

```
str.split(/\s(?:!|\|)\s/);
```

(I put the alternation in a non-capturing group to control what was in the alternation.)

But again, for just two *characters* (rather than two different expressions), you're better off with a character class:

```
str.split(/\s[!|]\s/);
```